# Rails cancan user that have many users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid, cancan

I am trying to do a system that have users that have users. So far there is no problem. I create two roles, :employee and :boss, a boss can have many employee, and an employee have to have one boss.

I use devise, cancan, mongoid on a rails application, the problem is setting the ability.rb file, I think that it's ok, but when I try to test it on rspec, it fails.

The ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not log in)

    alias_action :read, :create, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud

    if user.role? == :boss
      can :crud, User do |people|
        user.users.include?( people )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the spec file:

```
require 'cancan'
require 'cancan/matchers'
require_relative '../../app/models/ability.rb'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Ability do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  describe "role user system" do
    context "when there are a boss" do

      before(:each)do
        @user = user
        @ability = Ability.new(@user)
        @emplo = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :role => :employee, :user => @user)
      end

      it "allows to crud employees" do
        @ability.should be_able_to(:crud, @emplo)
      end

      it "denies a non boss user to manage employees" do
        ability1 = Ability.new(FactoryGirl.create(:user, :role => :employee))
        ability1.should_not be_able_to(:manage, @emplo)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The factory create the user as boss by default. I run the test and obtain:

```
Ability
  role user system
    when there are a boss
      allows to crud employees (FAILED - 1)
      denies a non boss user to manage employees

Failures:

  1) Ability role user system when there are a boss allows to crud employees
     Failure/Error: @ability.should be_able_to(:crud, @emplo)
       expected to be able to :crud #<User _id: 518b5a860009d6307f000002, _type: nil, 
       email: "user-2@example.org", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$OJeSUDPFf223r79jJP6odeBcuRoBJa1y0u3omOnAsE7SUyPwtgdmW", 
       reset_password_token: nil,  reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, 
       sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, 
       last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: 2013-05-09 08:12:54 UTC, 
       confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, address: "C\\ Romeo love Julieta street, 9, 5º A", 
       name: "fooname", surname: "foosurname", phone: "+34957957957", role: :employee, user_id: "518b5a860009d6307f000001">
```

What I'm doing wrong, I search in internet but I don't find the answer.
Thanks you.

PD:
I have refactoriced on the ability.rb file

```
if user.role? == :boss 
  can :crud, User do |people| 
    user.users.include?( people ) 
  end 
end
```

for

```
if user.role? == :boss 
  can :crud, User, User.where(:user_id => user.id) 
end
```

still have the same problem, but is more legible now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the problem, I put the solution for other newbe like me:

```
if user.role? == :boss 
  can :crud, User, User.where(:user_id => user.id)
end
```

This have to change for:

```
if user.role? == :boss 
  can :crud, User, :user_id => user.id
end
```